# Use of toggle button in <summary>

Tags: html

I am trying to place a toggle button in a `<summary>` element, using the toggle button here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

It works fine on Firefox, but on Chrome, clicking on the toggle button actually toggles the `<details>` element instead of the toggle button. If I use the rounded version instead, I can toggle the toggle button if I click on the corner of the toggle button (the region that is no longer colored grey/blue because of the rounding), but not if I click on the interior.

What can I do to make it work on Chrome? Which of the two behaviors is "correct"?

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </summary>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean in my opinion it's not exactly good UX, but to keep it simple and semantic, just separate the ambiguity in the actionable elements and their respective events they require. Eg;

```css
.switch-summary-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.switch-summary-container aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: -.5rem;
  left: 1rem;
}

summary {
  min-height: 40px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="switch-summary-container">
  <aside>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </aside>
  <details>
    <summary>
    </summary>
    Words Words Words.
  </details>
</section>
```